# How can a set be closed and bounded but not compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

In Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis(3E), Chapter 2, Exercise 16 says let E be the set $ E = \{ p \in\Bbb Q \mid 2 < p^2 <3\} $, where $\Bbb Q$ is the set of all rationals as a metric space with $d(p,q) = |p -q|$.

You are asked to show that $E$ is closed and bounded in $\Bbb Q$ but that $E$ is not compact? But is not the definition of compact that the set is closed and bounded?

You are also asked to show the set is open in $\Bbb Q$, when you have just showed it is closed in $\Bbb Q$?

I am not asking how to do this problem, I am just asking how this problem is even a question when it seems it is contradicting itself. Is there a loophole I am not seeing?

Comment: The result you are applying requires the space should be a **complete** metric space. $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete in the metric given. Think of a sequence of rationals converging to some irrational.

Comment: For a metric space, the definition of compact is not "closed and bounded". Since you are using a textbook, how does the author define "compact"?

Comment: It is a **theorem** (not a definition) that a set in a *complete* metric space is compact if and only if it is closed and (totally) bounded.  In a lot of books on real analysis, authors will state that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded, which is true since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is complete, and bounded implies totally bounded there.  Indeed, they may even define compactness to mean closed and bounded, since the universe of discourse is $\mathbb{R}$ (or a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$).  However, the actual definitions are more nuanced.

Comment: A metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded. In $\mathbb R^n$, a subset is closed if and only if  it is complete, and bounded if and only if it is totally bounded. Thus for subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, compact $\iff$ closed and bounded, but this doesn't hold in a general metric space.

Comment: For the record, a metric space is called proper if every closed bounded subset is compact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two major misconceptions in your question:

1. You are assuming that a closed and bounded set is compact by *definition*.  In fact, this is not the definition of a compact set.  In the most general setting, a compact set is one such that every open cover has a finite subcover (this is a moderately technical topological definition, which depends on what you mean by an "open set," a "cover," and a "subcover").  If you don't want to get into the nitty-gritty of topology, you can define compact sets in metric spaces in terms of sequential compactness.  A set is sequentially compact if every sequence in that space has a convergent subsequence.  In metric spaces, it turns out that compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent.

   On the other hand, what you assert as the *definition* of a compact set is, in fact, a *theorem* which can be proved under certain hypotheses.  For example, in real analysis you have the [Heine-Borel Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem), which states that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.  If you are taking a course in real analysis, you *might* see this given as the definition of compactness in order to avoid topological or sequential technicalities, however it is important to note that this is not a definition which works in all metric spaces.  Indeed, Rudin almost certainly gives this exercise in order to demostrate the importance of the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ for analysis.

   More generally, the Heine-Borel Theorem gives us a way of describing some of the things that can go wrong.  A metric space is said to have the *Heine-Borel Property* if every closed, bounded set is compact.  Incomplete metric spaces fail to have the Heine-Borel property–essentially, if you can find a Cauchy sequence which fails to converge, then you can cover that sequence with balls in such a way that no finite subcover exists.  There are also more interesting examples–for example, the Hilbert space of square integrable functions over $\mathbb{R}$ fails to have the Heine-Borel Property, despite being a complete metric space.
2. Open and closed are not opposites.  I don't remember how deep Rudin goes into the topology of $\mathbb{R}$, but a standard approach in real analysis classes is, essentially, as follows:

   - A set $U$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ is said to be *open* if for every $x \in U$ there exists some $r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq U$, where
     $$ B(x,r) = \{ y \in X : d(x,y) < r \} $$
     denotes the *open ball* of radius $r$ centered at $x$.  That is, by choosing a radius small enough, we can find a ball entirely contained in $U$ which contains $x$.
   - A set $K \subseteq (X,d)$ is *closed* if its complement $K^\complement = X \setminus K$ is open.

   It may look like these are complete opposites, but they aren't quite.  For example, the sets $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are both open and closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (Exercise:  convince yourself that this is true).  Such sets are sometimes called "clopen" sets.

   More generally, in a discrete metric space, *all* sets are clopen.  To see this, recall that the discrete metric is given by
   $$ d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x=y$, and} \\ 1 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$
   But then $B(x,1/2) = \{ x \}$, which implies that if $x \in A$ for any set $A$, then $B(x,1/2) \subseteq A$.  Thus every set $A$ is open.  But if every set is open, then $A^\complement$ is also open, which means that $(A^\complement)^\complement = A$ is closed.  Therefore $A$ is clopen.

   In short, contrary to your intuition, "closed" does not imply "not open".  That is, a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be open, even if it is closed.  There is a video out there called "[Hitler Learns Topology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw)" which may be moderately enlightening and, hopefully, more than moderately entertaining.

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation of the terms involved here.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I am quite new to real analysis.